# Set DIR="LTR" for every language

Tags: wordpress, directory, arabic, right-to-left

I'm using wordpress / divi theme.

How do I make sure if it's AR (arabic) it always stays LTR.

Right now its showing: html lang="ar" dir="rtl"

I need it to show: html lang="ar" dir="**ltr**"

You can view the site here: 
pastebin.com/TdgT0489

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,
Michael

Comment: Isn't arabic rtl?

Comment: Yes, of course it is. This is for my own purpose.

Comment: Just check the header.php file, how the dir="rtl" gets generated. It is also possible, it is added by multilingual plugin if there is one.

Comment: I don't use a multilingual plugin, and I set each RTL to LTR in PHP. It's strange.

Comment: What is the code for <html ... in header.php?

Comment: It's standard for wordpress. It is there for when you select a language it applies it to the whole site.

So, if AR is selected it'll automatically switch to RTL. What I did was go to every DIR="RTL" line and replaced it with DIR="LTR", but still RTL shows up in that line.

Comment: It still sounds to me you have a multilingual plugin installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("html").attr("dir", "ltr")
});
</script>
```

This is the code to make it work. This replaces the RTL and makes it LTR. I changed the "$" to "jQuery"

All the best!